# How to add auto-incrementing semver tags to a GHCR container?

Tags: docker, github-actions

I recently added my application to ghcr, and noticed that the default non-`latest` SHA signature tags aren't very readable. I wanted to add automatically increasing semver tags, but I've had no success getting the tags to display on the container versions.

I've tried several methods of pushing the container, usually using the `anothrNick/github-tag-action` to generate the tags (which works) but the containers never have the correct semver tag, only the SHA sig and the main tag. The `latest` tag seems to have been left behind at some point as well, although I suspect if I add it to `tags` it will reappear. The `docker/metadata-action` template doesn't work either, although that's what I based the template I have right now on.

Workflow run results are [here](https://github.com/SkySourced/findtheducks/actions/workflows/docker-publish.yml) and my actions file is as follows:

```yaml
name: increase-tag
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - v*
jobs:

  publish:
    name: Publish
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Log in to GHCR
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          registry: ghcr.io
          username: ${{ github.actor }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Extract metadata
        id: meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@v3
        with: 
          images: ghcr.io/skysourced/findtheducks

      - name: Build and push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          context: .
          push: true
          tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
          labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}
```

There is another job that runs after, which SSHs into the deployment server and pulls the container, but I didn't think it would be relevant to include here.

Thanks!

Comment: I recommend using `mathieudutour/github-tag-action@v6.1`